# Why doesn't the first plot appear when I source an R file with 2 print ggplot commands?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
g.rank <- ggplot(data = train, aes(Result, RankDiff)) +
          geom_boxplot(fill = c("#FFF59D", "#EF9A9A", "#A5D6A7")) 
print(g.rank)

g.diff <- ggplot(data = train, aes(Result, DiffDiff)) +
          geom_boxplot(fill = c("#FFF59D", "#EF9A9A", "#A5D6A7")) 
print(g.diff)
```

The first plot doesn't appear in the plot history in Rstudio when I source the R file that contains the above code.

Comment: works for me (I don't know what the `train` data is, but if I use e.g. iris dataset to make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)) - can scroll back to see both plots in RStudio. Perhaps it is RStudio specific (I have 0.99.473)

Comment: Also works... btw dont forget your library calls in your script